# What is the correct VIM regexp to search to get = but not ==?

Tags: regex, vim

In the following code:

```
a = b = c == 1
```

I'd like to match on only the first two =, but not the == at the end.

I figured the pattern `\<=\>` would work since `\<` matches beginning of word and `\>` matches the end. But it doesn't. What's wrong with this pattern and what is the correct pattern?

Comment: I also wonder why `\b=\b` doesn't work... anyone?

Comment: `\<` and `\>` delimit a word composed of "keyword characters" defined by the `'iskeyword'` option. `=` is not part of `'iskeyword'`.

Comment: \b=\b wont match because `=` is not word

Answer (score 5, accepted):

vim supports lookarounds, so you can use a negative lookbehind and negative lookahead surrounding the =.  This will match only the desired = and even = at the start or end of the line.

```
\(=\)\@<!=\(=\)\@!
```

Comment: Thanks. This works, but what's wrong with the anchors? Presumably they are supposed to do the same thing?

Comment: @me2 the word boundaries (`\<` and `\>`) match the beginning and end of words.  I believe that a word boundary is a character that is next to a character that is of different word status.  For example in `a=`, `a` would be a word boundary for `=`.  In `==`, that's still a whole word.

Comment: You don’t have to use groups in such simple cases. `=\@<!==\@!` works just as good.

Comment: @ZyX thanks for the clarification; I didn't think to try it without the groups; I only saw examples with groups

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use `\<=\>` because usually, the equals character is **not** a *keyword character*. You *could* fix that with `:set iskeyword+==`, but that may have side effects for navigating and syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

This regex should work:

```
[^=]=[^=]
```

It will break if you want to match single `=` at the beginning or at the end of line - but I figured this is not an issue for your patterns.

Comment: This won't work if `=` is the beginning of the line. Looking for a way to make the anchors work properly.